# Does anyone know why the product_id is no longer saved in the sales_order_item table?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.3

I recently noticed that Magento no longer seems to be storing the `product_id` in the `sales_order_item` table.
As a workaround I now use the `sku` to retrieve the product associated with the order item but I was wondering when this change happened.

Answer (score -1):

Magento 2.3.3 is not removed `product_id` from `sales_order_item` table.
Please check any extension is removing the column from the table.

Comment: Hi Nandish, thanks but I think you misunderstood. The column is still there but it does not seem to be used anymore.